# What are the differences between production mode and development mode with webpack build?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-redux, react-dom

I have a completely empty project and by that I mean I just have a single file with 3 top dependencies to react, react-dom, and react-redux.

I'm trying to understand what webpack is doing in each case, with a bare minimal example.

I use these npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "client": "webpack -w --mode production --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "client-dev": "webpack -w --mode development --config ./webpack.config.js"
  },
```

and get this output:

[image]

from a single file / entry point:

```
// React Modules
import React        from 'react';
import ReactDOM     from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between of those two option are

In development
Sets `process.env.NODE_ENV` on `DefinePlugin` to value `development`. Enables useful names for modules and chunks.

in production
Sets `process.env.NODE_ENV` on `DefinePlugin` to value `production`. Enables `deterministic mangled` names for modules and chunks, `FlagDependencyUsagePlugin`, `FlagIncludedChunksPlugin`, `ModuleConcatenationPlugin`, `NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin` and `TerserPlugin`.

cc from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode where you can read and see some examples of it being used.

Comment: thanks, i was looking for a simple explanation as to why it takes 6x build time for production.  is it simply minifying all the packages for that long 7 seconds?